# Unnesting groups from LSD.test (agricolae)

Tags: r, unnest

Forgive me if this has been asked before.  I am using the following code to create a list of groups, produced with LSD.test (agricolae) and nested by id.

```
lsd_groups <- dataset %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(lsd_statistics = LSD.test(lm(value  ~ book_name + treatment_name, data=.), 
                                "treatment_name", alpha=0.1)$groups) %>%
  unnest()
```

My problem is when I unnest the results, I use the identifiers (treatment names) associated with the means in the grouping.

I know if I were to leave the LSD.test output as a list, I could see the treatment names by running:

```
lsd_groups$lsd_statistics[[1]]
```

I could also convert the treatment names, which are stored as row.names, to a column.

I was hoping, though, for a more elegant solution using unnest().  Is there any way to instruct unnest() to keep those row names?  Alternatively, is there a way to tell LSD.test to list the treatment names in a column instead of assigning them as row names?  Thank you.